# Why does ScrollView not scroll to bottom?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

**RoomView.swift**

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    
    ScrollView {
        VStack  {
            LazyVGrid(columns: twoColumnGrid, alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(roomData.newItems, id: \.id) { item in
                    
                    VStack{
                        ItemView(lastDeleted: $recentDeletedItems, item: item, roomData: roomData)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: roomData.lastItemID) { id in
        print("ID Changed: \(String(describing: id))")
        withAnimation { proxy.scrollTo(id, anchor: .bottom) }
    }
    .onAppear(perform: {
        proxy.scrollTo(roomData.lastItemID, anchor: .bottom)
    })
    
}
```

On adding new items, the print statement inside .onChange prints the correct lastItemID but still it won't scroll to bottom. What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you using a binding with ForEach?

Comment: Put `.id(item.id)` at the end of the `VStack` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that binding. It was unnecessary and I overlooked it because nothing seems broken.

Comment: Putting .id(item.id) on the VStack did the trick. Thank you so much.